# C#: Is there a way to search a string for a number without using regex?

Tags: c#, string, search

Is there a way to check to see if a string contains any numeric digits in it without using regex? I was thinking of just splitting it into an array and running a search on that, but something tells me there is an easier way:

```
//pseudocode
string aString = "The number 4"

If (aString contains a number) Then enter validation loop
Else return to main

//output
"The string contains a number. Are you sure you want to continue?"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String.IndexOfAny` as:

```
bool isNumeric = mystring.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()) > -1;
```

Comment: thanks. i went with this and it worked out great. im gonna look into leppie's suggestion as well!

Answer (score 10):

```
var containsdigit = somestring.Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: cool thanks. I see that if (words.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsDigit)) would return the same as if (words.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()) > -1)

Comment: is there a method to check for special characters too? Im not seeing it right away

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: It is almost functionally the same. `IsDigit` will check for some Unicode cases too. `IsNumber` does even more, like fractions.

Comment: doesnt seem to be catching special characters, so far IndexOfAny is though. I just assumed there were already be a method for this. Pretty common, no?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: `char.IsDigit()` also returns true for chars like `۴`, `൦` and `৮`. This may be perfect, disasterous or irrelevant depending on your case, which is a reason in itself for not having a single method to do this - there's no single correct way for all cases - along with the fact that if every commonly used one-line method string could support were added, the interface would be epic in length.

Comment: i see your point. Maybe a user class method for common special characters found on a standard keyboard would be in order? I'm in my first programming "language" class, but ive already learned a ton from picking apart what ive learned in this thread. I didn't realize that you can keep tacking on methods based on the previous method's return type

Comment: Well, a single "standard keyboard" doesn't really exist. There's no ৮ on my keyboard, but that would be a pretty ridiculous keyboard for someone trying to write Bengali. Meanwhile, what is on my keyboard is probably slightly different to yours unless you're Irish. Finally, a lot of people won't care what's on their keyboard as long as they can access certain chars another way. So just with that one perspective you have a lot of complexity and what's needed is a string class that is relatively simple, and a lot of methods and classes that help in different ways. Which is what we have.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extension method for string and use a combination of LINQ and the [Char.IsNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8t708dh.aspx) function e.g.

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool ContainsNumber(this string str)
    {
        return str.Any(c => Char.IsNumber(c)); 
    }
}
```

Then your logic would look like:

```
//pseudocodestring 
string str = "The number 4";
If (aString.ContainsNumber())
    enter validation
```